# "Template not found" error when attempting to access static web page

Tags: craft3, routing

I'm pretty new to craft and I inherited a site that hosts a map from MapBox as a static html file in the `/web` folder, so something like `/web/map/old-map/index.html`.  Hitting `mysite.org/map/old-map` directly returns the map, as expected.

So I figured that if I duplicated the `old-map` folder and renamed it `new-map` I would instantly see the old map in the new map directory at `mysited.org/map/new-map`.  But instead I get:

```
81828384858687888990919293949596979899    {
        // Does that template exist?
        if (
            (
                Craft::$app->getConfig()->getGeneral()->headlessMode &&
                Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsSiteRequest()
            ) ||
            !$this->getView()->doesTemplateExist($template)
        ) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Template not found: ' . $template);
        }
 
        // Merge any additional route params
        $routeParams = Craft::$app->getUrlManager()->getRouteParams();
        unset($routeParams['template'], $routeParams['template']);
        $variables = array_merge($variables, $routeParams);
 
        return $this->renderTemplate($template, $variables);
    }
 1. craft\controllers\TemplatesController::actionRender('map/new-map', [])
```

So I checked the Routes on the site to see if the previous dev had made a special route for old-map.  Nope.

So I checked Retour to see if there were any relevant redirects there.  Nope.

So I checked the `.htaccess` file to see if a special accommodation had been made for the original dev's map.  As expected, nope.  Just the regular Craft `.htaccess` file.

I also reset the cache which I didn't really expect to have a salutary effect and it didn't.

Then I ran out of ideas.  Anyone else have one?

Answer (score 5):

The problem was specific to my local set up.  The dockerfile for this project did not mount the entire /web/ folder, so the live application was ignoring local changes I made to it.

Solution:
Change dockerfile to mount the whole web folder.